# Dataflow pipeline "lost contact with the service"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm running into trouble with an Apache Beam pipline on Google Cloud Dataflow.

The pipeline is simple: Reading json from GCS, extracting text from some nested fields, writing back to GCS.

It works fine when testing with a smaller subset of input files but when I run it on the full data set, I get the following error (after running fine through around 260M items).

Somehow the "worker eventually lost contact with the service"

```
  (8662a188e74dae87): Workflow failed. Causes: (95e9c3f710c71bc2): S04:ReadFromTextWithFilename/Read+FlatMap(extract_text_from_raw)+RemoveLineBreaks+FormatText+WriteText/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles/Do+WriteText/Write/WriteImpl/Pair+WriteText/Write/WriteImpl/WindowInto(WindowIntoFn)+WriteText/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Reify+WriteText/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Write failed., (da6389e4b594e34b): A work item was attempted 4 times without success. Each time the worker eventually lost contact with the service. The work item was attempted on: 
  extract-tags-150110997000-07261602-0a01-harness-jzcn,
  extract-tags-150110997000-07261602-0a01-harness-828c,
  extract-tags-150110997000-07261602-0a01-harness-3w45,
  extract-tags-150110997000-07261602-0a01-harness-zn6v
```

The Stacktrace shows a `Failed to update work status`/`Progress reporting thread got error` error:

```
Exception in worker loop: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 776, in run deferred_exception_details=deferred_exception_details) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 629, in do_work exception_details=exception_details) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 168, in wrapper return fun(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 490, in report_completion_status exception_details=exception_details) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 298, in report_status work_executor=self._work_executor) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/workerapiclient.py", line 333, in report_status self._client.projects_locations_jobs_workItems.ReportStatus(request)) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/clients/dataflow/dataflow_v1b3_client.py", line 467, in ReportStatus config, request, global_params=global_params) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 723, in _RunMethod return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 729, in ProcessHttpResponse self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 600, in __ProcessHttpResponse http_response.request_url, method_config, request) HttpError: HttpError accessing <https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/qollaboration-live/locations/us-central1/jobs/2017-07-26_16_02_36-1885237888618334364/workItems:reportStatus?alt=json>: response: <{'status': '400', 'content-length': '360', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Wed, 26 Jul 2017 23:54:12 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "(7f8a0ec09d20c3a3): Failed to publish the result of the work update. Causes: (7f8a0ec09d20cd48): Failed to update work status. Causes: (afa1cd74b2e65619): Failed to update work status., (afa1cd74b2e65caa): Work \"6306998912537661254\" not leased (or the lease was lost).", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } } >
```

And Finally:

```
HttpError: HttpError accessing <https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/[projectid-redacted]/locations/us-central1/jobs/2017-07-26_18_28_43-10867107563808864085/workItems:reportStatus?alt=json>: response: <{'status': '400', 'content-length': '358', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Thu, 27 Jul 2017 02:00:10 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "(5845363977e915c1): Failed to publish the result of the work update. Causes: (5845363977e913a8): Failed to update work status. Causes: (44379dfdb8c2b47): Failed to update work status., (44379dfdb8c2e88): Work \"9100669328839864782\" not leased (or the lease was lost).", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } } >
at __ProcessHttpResponse (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py:600)
at ProcessHttpResponse (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py:729)
at _RunMethod (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py:723)
at ReportStatus (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/clients/dataflow/dataflow_v1b3_client.py:467)
at report_status (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/workerapiclient.py:333)
at report_status (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py:298)
at report_completion_status (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py:490)
at wrapper (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py:168)
at do_work (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py:629)
at run (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py:776)
```

This looks like an error to the data flow internals to me. Can anyone confirm? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

The HttpError typically appears *after* the workflow has failed and is part of the failure/teardown process.

It looks like there were others error reported in your pipeline, such as the following. Note that if the same elements fail 4 times it will be marked failing.

Try looking the [Stack Traces](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dataflow-monitoring-intf#error-reporting) section in the UI to identify the other errors and their stack traces. Since this only occurs on the larger dataset, consider the possibility of their being malformed elements that only exist in the larger dataset.

Comment: I was mainly looking at the error messages in stacktrace before, but looks like there are some error-like messages in the info section as well. Updating the question with additional details

Comment: Did you look in the "Stack Trace" tab of the UI as suggested in the article? Specifically, there should be messages that aren't about reporting status -- these should be the ones that indicate the actual problem in your code. It looks like you just added more information from the Job Logs tab.

Comment: the http error is the only one that's in the stack traces tab. the rest I posted is from stack driver.